# @ManyToMany, using a View

Tags: hibernate, jpa-2.0

I'm having troubles with a @ManyToMany property on my Entity 'Location'.
The location contains a parent/child relationship with other Locations, so it basically represents a tree of locations.
(Location A contains children A1, A2 and Location A2 contains another Location B, etc.)

No rocket science.

Since this is a well know 'tree' and Hibernate / JPA do not support Hierarchical queries, I've added a readonly ManyToMany relation 'allParents'. This collection contains, like the name already said, all parents going upwards in the tree.
To achieve this, I've created a view which is used as jointable in the mapping.

Also here, No rocket science. all works fine.

Note that I never use Cascade operations.

The problem arises when I want to delete a Location.
This delete tries to delete also records in that jointable (which is indeed normally the case), but this obviously does not work on a view. (at least, not my view).

So, I am looking for a way to mark this association read-only. 
The @Immutable does not seem to do the job.

(always getting the exception: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: cannot delete from view "allnamedparents")

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Thanks in advance!

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "location")
public class Location extends AbstractAuditingEntity implements {


    @OneToMany()
    @JoinColumn(name = "parent_id", foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name = "FK_location_parent"))
    private Set<AbstractLocation> childLocations = new LinkedHashSet<>();


    @Column(name="parent_id", updatable = false,insertable = false)
    private Long parentId;

    @Immutable()
    @ManyToMany()
    @JoinTable(
            name = "allnamedparents",
            joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "locationid", referencedColumnName = "id")},
            inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "parentid", referencedColumnName = "id")}
            )
    private List<AbstractLocation> allParents = new ArrayList<>();



}
```

Comment: Which version of hibernate do you have?

Comment: I'm using Hibernate 5.3.7

Comment: Did you tried add CascadeType.REFRESH only?

Comment: CascadeType.REFRESH dit not help either. (I'm not sure why this would help, since I think this affects the stuff that needs to happen to related entities. This problem relates to the jointable.